# Flutter project on Mac (copied from Windows)

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter

I received Flutter project from friend to build iOS version of the app on the Mac (Catalina & Xcode 11.3). The Flutter project is made in Windows and made for Android. Now I should make iOS version on Mac of the same project.

I and my friend are very new to Flutter. I have little experience of Xcode (building exported Unity projects).

I want to understand what Flutter needs to be working. I can create test project and run it in the simulator. But this project doesn't work.

Output of **flutter doctor -v** seems to be fine:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57,
    locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at
      /Users/donkeygames/Development/Flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (2 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/donkeygames/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3, Build version 11C29
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • 41E09B8C-2D5A-4F0E-8557-2C93BE37B6E6 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

I try to clean build folder and re-create the project:

**flutter clean**
**flutter create .**

```
Recreating project ....
  ios/.gitignore (created)
  ios/Assets/.gitkeep (created)
  ios/alylatu.podspec (created)
  ios/Classes/TestAppPlugin.m (created)
  ios/Classes/SwiftTestAppPlugin.swift (created)
  ios/Classes/TestAppPlugin.h (created)
  example/ios/Runner.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Info.plist (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@2x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage@3x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/README.md (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/Contents.json
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.imageset/LaunchImage.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-76x76@2x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@1x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@1x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@1x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.pn
  g (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.pn
  g (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@3x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-20x20@2x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@3x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@2x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-60x60@3x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-60x60@2x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-76x76@1x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-40x40@3x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@2x.png
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard (created)
  example/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
  (created)
  example/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/Runner.xcscheme (created)
  example/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig (created)
  example/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig (created)
  example/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist (created)
  example/ios/.gitignore (created)
  example/test/widget_test.dart (created)
  example/alylatu_example.iml (created)
  example/.gitignore (created)
  example/.metadata (created)
  example/android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  example/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png (created)
  example/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png (created)
  example/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml (created)
  example/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (created)
  example/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png (created)
  example/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml (created)
  example/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png (created)
  example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  example/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  example/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties (created)
  example/android/gradle.properties (created)
  example/android/.gitignore (created)
  example/android/settings.gradle (created)
  example/android/app/build.gradle (created)
  example/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/shahxad/TestApp_example/MainActivity.k
  t (created)
  example/android/build.gradle (created)
  example/android/TestApp_example_android.iml (created)
  example/pubspec.yaml (created)
  example/README.md (created)
  example/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h (created)
  example/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift (created)
  example/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj (created)
  example/lib/main.dart (created)
  example/.idea/runConfigurations/main_dart.xml (created)
  example/.idea/libraries/Flutter_for_Android.xml (created)
  example/.idea/libraries/Dart_SDK.xml (created)
  example/.idea/libraries/KotlinJavaRuntime.xml (created)
  example/.idea/modules.xml (created)
  example/.idea/workspace.xml (created)
Running "flutter pub get" in example...                             4.6s

Wrote 74 files.                             

All done!
[✓] Flutter: is fully installed. (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X
    10.15.2 19C57, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices: is fully installed.
    (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS: is fully installed. (Xcode 11.3)
[✓] Android Studio: is fully installed. (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device: is fully installed. (1 available)

In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd example
  $ flutter run

Your application code is in example/lib/main.dart.

Your plugin code is in ./lib/TestApp.dart.

Host platform code is in the "android" and "ios" directories under ..
To edit platform code in an IDE see
https://flutter.dev/developing-packages/#edit-plugin-package.
```

**flutter run lib/TestApp.dart**

```
Launching lib/TestApp.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Expected ios/Runner.xcodeproj but this file is missing.
No application found for TargetPlatform.ios.
Is your project missing an ios/Runner/Info.plist?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

**flutter build ios lib/alylatu.dart**

```
Expected ios/Runner.xcodeproj but this file is missing.
Application not configured for iOS
```

I even tried to copy files from test project to TestApp folders, but that doesn't worked.

Should I configure the TestApp project to iOS project?
I don't have Brew installed. Should I install that and something else?

Any ideas?

Comment: Try running `flutter create .` in the projet folder.

Comment: Is the project an application, or a plugin? The `flutter create` output shows it creating files for a plugin, not an application, but you are trying to run it as if it were an application.

Comment: Some files are missing perhaps deleted Run flutter create ios

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

1) Create a new flutter project.
2) Run the project and ensure it runs smoothly.
3) Once you verify that the project runs, go to your new project in :

- ProjectDirecectory
- iOS folder

Copy the following:

Runner.xcodeproj and Runner.xcworkspace

Paste these into your old project (Project/ios) then save and run. This worked for me and hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error as the following:

```
      Expected ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj but this file is missing.
      No application found for TargetPlatform.ios.
      Is your project missing an ios/Runner/Info.plist?
      Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.
```

Problem was that I cloned the project from a Git Repository. project.pbxproj file was in .gitignore. So, I created a new flutter project and copied other files into this.

[image]